# Why is my Broadcom wireless card not working even after installing the b43 driver?

Tags: wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. Network controller is BCM4311, lap top is a Dell Latitude D830. I've updated, upgraded, installed firmware-b43-installer, fwcutter, and it's still not detecting my wireless internet. iwconfig says no wireless extensions for lo or etho even though the controller is detected. Trying to manually add the wireless network through network manager also hasn't worked. It's just not detecting the wireless network.

[Showing the driver is apparently working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p93y.png)

And the output from lshw -c network:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fe8fc000-fe8fffff
```

Output from rfkill list all:

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

What else can I try? All of the solutions I've seen have said that fwcutter and the firmware-b43-installer are the answer but they haven't been working for me.

Comment: Did you reboot? unclaimed = no driver/module loaded. Please reboot and paste output of lsmod.

Comment: Yes, I rebooted. Here is the lsmod output:

Comment: [lsmod output](http://i.imgur.com/lqpkR.png)

Comment: [lsmod output part 2](http://i.imgur.com/t7ckU.png)

Comment: It's still using the wl driver -- uninstall that please. (no b43 in list...)

Comment: Ok, I did "sudo rmmod wl" and then did lsmod. wl is no longer listed there. Then did "sudo modprobe b43" and then "lsmod" and b43 is now listed. Now what? still no wireless network.

Comment: Wait, nevermind! There it is! Thank you so much for your help. I never would have figured that out. :)  :)

Comment: Good to know, Dale! I will add an answer in a few hours so others can refer to it, as well as how to remove wl permanently or you'll have to keep doing this rmmod/mod probe everytime you boot. You'll be notified when the answer is posted, so please do take a moment to come back and accept it (that way people know the answer "worked" :)

Comment: I will. I just discovered that I did in fact have to go in manually and remove wl and add b43 all over again after reboot.

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen at the comments, [izx](https://askubuntu.com/users/58612/izx) helped the OP to solve the problem, but he never posted an answer and he was last seen 10 months ago, so I'm posting this based on OP's comments.

Run:

```
sudo rmmod wl
```

to remove **wl** module and:

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

to load **b43** module.

You can force **b43** loading and prevent **wl** loading at boot by running:

```
echo "b43" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
echo "blacklist wl" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-wl.conf
```